# ls with find :: report total size

Tags: bash, find, ls

I am trying to get the total size of files satisfying a `find`, e.g.:

```
ls  $(find -maxdepth 2 -type f)
```

However, this kind of invocation of `ls` does not produce the total size as well.

Comment: many of the below solution hope that the filenames can "fit" on a du -ch line, which may not be the case. So it would then print several partial results instead of the global sum. See my solution for an alternative which should work in "all" cases (and is portable as it doesn't depend on GNU find, GNU xargs, and not even on recent find options such as "printf")

Comment: Those other solution of course are neat, though, and will work in many cases (the commandline can be huge, especially on recent systems!). But "ymmv", and huge directories occur too...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Believe it or not you can do this with `find` and `du`. I used a similar technique that I wrote up on my blog a while a go. That article is titled: [[one-liner]: Calculating Disk Space Usage for a List of Files Using du under Linux](http://www.lamolabs.org/blog/5833/calculating-disk-space-usage-list-files-using-du-under-linux/).

The gist of that post is a command such as this:

```
$ find -maxdepth 2 -type f | tr '\n' '\0' | du -ch --files0-from=-
```

#### Example

This will list the size of all the files along with a summary total.

```
$ find -maxdepth 2 -type f | tr '\n' '\0' | du -ch --files0-from=- | tail -10
0   ./92086/2.txt
0   ./92086/5.txt
0   ./92086/14.txt
0   ./92086/19.txt
0   ./92086/18.txt
0   ./92086/17.txt
4.0K    ./load.bash
4.0K    ./100855/plain.txt
4.0K    ./100855/tst_ccmds.bash
21M total
```

**NOTE:** This solution requires that `du` support the `--files0-from=` switch which is a GNU switch, to my knowledge.

*excerpt from du man page*

```
--files0-from=F
          summarize disk usage of the NUL-terminated file names specified in 
          file F; If F is - then read names from standard input
```

Also this method suffers from not being able to deal with special characters in file names, such as spaces and non-printables.

#### Examples

```
du: cannot access `./101415/fileD': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `E': No such file or directory
```

These could be dealt with by introducing more `tr .. ..` commands to substitute them with alternative characters. However there is a better way, if you have access to GNU's `find`.

#### Improvements

If your version of `find` offers the `--print0` switch then you can use this incantation which deals with files that have spaces and/or special characters that aren't printable.

```
$ find -maxdepth 2 -type f -print0 | du -ch --files0-from=- | tail -10
0   ./92086/2.txt
0   ./92086/5.txt
0   ./92086/14.txt
0   ./92086/19.txt
0   ./92086/18.txt
0   ./92086/17.txt
4.0K    ./load.bash
4.0K    ./100855/plain.txt
4.0K    ./100855/tst_ccmds.bash
21M total
```

Answer (score 5):

`du` (disk usage) count the space files take up. Pass your found files to it and direct it to summarize (`-c`) and print in a human readable format (`-h`) instead of byte counts. Yo will then get the sizes of all the files concluded with a grand total. If you are only interested in this last line, you can then `tail` for it.

To also handle spaces in filenames, the delimiting symbol that `find` prints and `xargs` expects is set to the null symbol instead of the usual space.

```
find -maxdepth 2 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 du -ch | tail -n1
```

If you expect to find many files which burst the number of maximum arguments, xargs will split these into multiple `du` invocations. Then you could work around with replacing `tail` with a `grep`, that only shows the summarizing lines.

```
find -maxdepth 2 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 du -ch | grep -P '\ttotal$'
```

Comment: +1 It will fail for files with a space in their name, though.

Comment: It will fail too if the list of files is extremely long. You're literally expanding the entire list of files from the `$(find ..)` command, and passing it as args to `du -ch`. But in a pinch this is completely usable! Also suffers from spaces and non-printables.

Comment: It now cares for spaces and there is also a hint for an overwhelming argument list.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach : we just need the file size, and don't care about the file names, so we can get rid of any "weird" file names such as "names with CR in them, names with spaces, etc" :

```
 find /some/path -maxdepth 2 -type f -ls -exec printf '\000' \; \
     | tr -cd ' -~\000' \
     | tr '\000' '\n'   \
     | awk  '{ sum+=$7 } END { print "total size: ",sum }'
```

The trick is:

1) we print each file's "-ls" output,  FOLLOWED by a "\000" caracter (on the next line, but it's not a problem, see step 2)
  2) we get rid of **everything 'non-ascii-printable'** (including '\t' and '\n'. But we do keep also the **\000** in addition to the "regular" printable ascii, as we need it to know where the line of each file ends!). That way, filenames don't have anymore any quirks in them (no '\n', no '\t', no ';', etc). We do keep the spaces too, as we need those as well to find out the 7th field of "-ls", ie the filesize
 3) we translate the added '\000' into a '\n' (step 2) got rid of those too, in case some filenames contained them as well!)
 4) then we add the 7th column to get the final size in bytes.

This is very portable (don't need "-print0", etc)

Comment: I do it this way to 1) avoid limitation on the number of filenames  2) avoid any problem with any kind of filenames (they can not contain a '\000' by design)  3) portability: on many systems you don't have GNU find but a legacy one [mine doesn't even have `-printf ....` otherwise I could simply just output the filesize only...]

Comment: the steps 1), 2), 3) and 4) also correspond to the different lines in the command

Comment: The -maxdepth option isn't required by POSIX.

Comment: @JamesYoungman: I was taking the OP's options to better reflect his/her needs. But I don't have it on some of my systems, indeed. apart from that option, the rest should work on "any" unix system.

Answer (score 2):

If you're only going to compute the size of maximum two directory levels, why not call `du` directly?

```
du -ch dir/* dir/*/* | tail -1
```

This makes the shell expand the two levels of directories to a list of names and passes them as arguments to `du` which computes the sum.

Comment: `arg list too long` ?

Comment: @jlliagre Good point. I don't know the maximum number of arguments accepted by `du`, but this command is sufficient for most (trivial) cases I believe.

Comment: The limit is not from `du` but shell and eventually OS dependent (on Linux MAX_ARG_PAGES).

Answer (score 1):

`find -maxdepth 2 -type f --print0 | xargs -0 du -ch`

Comment: if the list of files is longer than the commandline allows, xargs will be called multiple times and you will have a grand total for each invocation.

Comment: Which is still more scalable than my approach, which will simply fail, when there are more files than possible arguments.

Comment: This will not work if there are any spaces or newlines in the filenames. You should use `... --print0 | xargs -0 du ...`

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple way that handles whatever odd file names that can be found:

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -type f -exec du -ch {} + | grep -w "total"
```

If there is a really large number of files under the current directory, you might have more than one total line displayed. There might be also unwanted total lines if some file names contain an isolated "`total`", eg: a file named "`Grand total file.txt`"